# Is there a way to output component data outside a component but inside the mounted div #app?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

Is something like this recommended in Vue 3 where you can output a variable from a component between the mounted `#app` div by using a `setup()` method in **main.js**? What would be good practise here? `ComponentA.data().someData` feels a bit off to me.

**component.php**

```
<div id="app">
   <component-a />

   <!-- Not quite sure if this is the right way... -->
   <!-- But would like to output the component data here instead of 
        inside the <template> of ComponentA if possible. -->
   <div>{{ ComponentA.data().someData }}</div> 
</div>
```

**main.js**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import componentA from '@/components/component-a';

const app = createApp({
    setup() {
        return {
            ComponentA
        }
    }
});

app.component('component-a', componentA);

app.mount("#app");
```

**component-a.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>Component A</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'ComponentA',
    data() {
        return {
            someData: 'this is some data',
        };
    },
};
</script>
```

Comment: but this is not a good practice, there's some patterns to communicate between components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely not a good idea (Vue 2 or Vue3), you should avoid having functions as part of template (other than for triggering action) because they don't get cached, so they will need to execute every time anything changes, slowing down the component rendering.

It's hard to give a definitive recommendation, since the request to access child component data is pretty generic, so I'll list two common patterns. The list is certainly not exhaustive as there are many creative ways to do this.

## Global store

If you use a globally accessible variable, both child and parent have access to it, no matter how far apart. The components don't even need to be descendants, since the data is globally accessible. One way to do this is with `Vuex`. But since you're using v3 (though v2.6+ has similar functionality via observables), you can use a data that is not attached to the component.

#### mydata.js

```js
import { ref } from 'vue';
export const someData = ref('this is some data');
```

Then you can use this anywhere

#### main.js

```js
import { someData } from './mydata.js';
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import componentA from '@/components/component-a';

const app = createApp({
    setup() {
        return {
            someData
        }
    }
});

app.component('component-a', componentA);

app.mount("#app");
```

and

#### App template

```html
<div id="app">
   <component-a />
   <div>{{ someData }}</div> 
</div>
```

and

#### component-a.vue

```html
<template>
    <div>Component A</div>
</template>

<script>
import { someData } from './mydata.js';
export default {
    name: 'ComponentA',
    setup() {
        someData.value="I'm now updated";
        return {};
    },
};
</script>
```

## Events

If you do have a direct parent/child relationship, and multiple instances of child, you might find that the global store is not a good fit, in which case you can use the "primary" way of dealing with this.

Props propagate down, events bubble up. So that means that if you want to access anything data that the child has, that the parent wouldn't, you can use events.

The common setup would be that you have the parent component setup a reactive variable that would update whenever the child data updates (this is more-or-less how `v-model` works)

#### component-a.vue

(not using composition api, emit works a bit different via setup())

```html
<template>
    <div>Component A</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'ComponentA',
    data() {
        return {
            someData: 'this is some data',
        };
    },
    watch: {
      someData: {
        immediate: true,
        handler(newValue, oldValue) {
          this.$emit('onDataChange', newValue)
        }
      }
    },
};
</script>
```

#### App template

```html
<div id="app">
   <component-a @onDataChange="updateMyData"/>
   <div>{{ myData }}</div> 
</div>
```

#### main.js

```js
import { createApp, ref } from 'vue';
import componentA from '@/components/component-a';

const app = createApp({
    setup() {
        const myData = ref('');
        const updateMyData = (data) => myData.value = data;
        return {
            myData, updateMyData
        }
    }
});

app.component('component-a', componentA);

app.mount("#app");
```